# Force HTML5 video into fullscreen autonomously

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, video, phonegap-plugins

I have a webpage with some embeded videos like

```
<video controls="controls" class="trumpetVideo" id="trumpetVideo">
<source src="videos/Trumpet_VP8.webm" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The webpage also contains other text and images.

My quesion is, how can I make the videos play AND go into fullscreen mode without user interaction? I understand that I can use HTML5's new fullscreen api, but if I use

```
var trumpet = $("#trumpetVideo");
var trumpet1 = trumpet[0];
trumpet1.mozRequestFullScreen();
trumpet1.play();
```

the javascript/developer console returns "Request for full-screen was denied because Element.mozRequestFullScreen() was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler." How can I bypass this? I'm not uploading the site for the public, its just going to be a display presentation on a tablet at a convention.

I can use HTML, Javascript, JQuery, Phonegap (and plugins)

Comment: Browser won't let you for security reasons. Full screen needs to be fired from a user event. As a work around, can you try setting the width/height of the video element to be the size of the viewport?

Comment: How?  I'm not a CSS techie.

Comment: And, I need to be able to do so systematically, using JQuery, so that the code can fullscreen and exit videos as they end.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is impossible to systematically enter fullscreen, due to security reasons. However, you can make the video take up all of the screen using CSS and JavaScript:

```js
/*
Use function start(); and exit();
to pause an play the video

*/




var trumpet = document.querySelector("#trumpetVideo");
var styleTag = document.createElement("style");
styleTag.innerHTML = `.fullscreen {
        position:fixed;
        border:none;
        overflow:hidden;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        }
        .in{
        background-color:black;
        }
        .gone{
                display:none;         
                }`;
document.head.appendChild(styleTag);

function start() {
  trumpet.classList.add("fullscreen");
  trumpet.play();
  document.body.classList.add("in");
  // OPTIONAL:          
  document.getElementById("wrapper").classList.add("gone");
}

function exit() {
  trumpet.classList.remove("fullscreen");
  trumpet.pause();
  document.body.classList.remove("in");
  document.getElementById("wrapper").classList.remove("gone");
}
```

```html
   <video id="trumpetVideo" loop>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
    <!--


    Video from w3schools 




    -->
<div id = "wrapper">
<button onclick = "start();">Start Video!!!</button>
        <button onclick = "stop();">End Video!!! (You can't see this button when it's in fullscreen)</button>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <p>Video courtesy of <a href="https://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.</p>
</div>
```

**[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d83fvjya/2/)**